# How to restrict entire FTS5 Query to a single column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Currently, I'm trying to execute an FTS5 query via libsqlite, and need to restrict the query to a specific column. In FTS4, this was possible by doing:

`SELECT foo, bar FROM tableName WHERE columnName MATCH ?`

and then binding the search string to the statement. However, with FTS5, the LHS of the MATCH operator must be the FTS table name itself, and the column name must be a part of the query:

`SELECT foo, bar FROM tableName WHERE tableName MATCH 'columnName:' || ?`.

This works when the `bind`ed string is a single phrase. However, consider the search text `this is great`. The query then becomes:

`SELECT foo, bar FROM tableName WHERE tableName MATCH 'columnName:pizza is great';`

Only `pizza` is restricted to to the `columnName`, but the rest of the phrase is matched against all columns.

How can I work around this?

Comment: CL., Thanks, edited to call it "search text"

Comment: Do you want the search text to be a single phrase or three phrases?

Comment: Three phrases, but the results should be restricted to a particular column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#full_text_query_syntax) says:

> A single phrase … may be restricted to matching text within a specified column of the FTS table by prefixing it with the column name followed by a colon character.

So the column name applies only to a single phrase.
If you have three phrases, you need to specify the column name three times:

```
tableName MATCH 'columnName:pizza columnName:is columnName:great'
```

Comment: I ran across this problem again recently, and realised that this solution isn't really feasible when you don't know the format of the search text.